# Atheros AR9285 hard blocked on toshiba nb305

Tags: wireless, hardware

My wireless card is hard blocked in any linux distro I install but there is no physical switch on netbook or on wifi card itself...I runned following commands :

inxi -N :

Network: Card-1: Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) driver: ath9k
 
Card-2: Realtek RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller driver: r8169

sudo rfkill list:

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes

any suggestions??

Comment: Usually there is a Fn+key of somesort to switch stuff on/off - e.g. Fn+F8  - is there a wireless symbol corresponding to your wireless Fn + key combination?

Comment: yes fn+f8 is the wireless switch key but the problem is it doesnt work....and all other function keys work :P

Comment: please add the output of `sudo lshw -class network` to your question.  Also look under the battery compartments - sometimes there is a slider, pushbutton there hidden away for wireless stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Toshiba c600. Installed Windows once and turned on Wi-Fi in there. After that, booted linux and the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> key works to swith wifi on and off.

Still can't use the laptop to share the wifi connection, but it connects to other wifi signals.